# PyQt5. QLineEdit не реагирует на сигнал

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Программа состоит из трех файлов. Проблема находится в файле page_2. При подключении сигнала returnPressed переменной url к функции, при нажатии на Return ничего не происходит. dumpObjectInfo говорит, что returnPressed подключен к unislot().

**page_2**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as widget
from PyQt5 import QtGui as gui
from PyQt5 import QtCore as core
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets as engine


class Page(widget.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        self.page = self.setupBrowser()
        self.page.load(core.QUrl('https://www.google.com'))
        self.url = self.setupUrl()

        self.url.dumpObjectInfo()

        self.buttons = self.setupButtons(self.page)

        self.setupLayout()

    def setupBrowser(self):
        return engine.QWebEngineView()

    def setupUrl(self):
        url = widget.QLineEdit()
        url.returnPressed.connect(self.xxx)
        return url

    def setupButtons(self, page):
        back = widget.QPushButton(gui.QIcon('back.png'), '')
        back.clicked.connect(page.back)

        forward = widget.QPushButton(gui.QIcon('forward.png'), '')
        forward.clicked.connect(page.forward)

        reload = widget.QPushButton(gui.QIcon('reload.png'), '')
        reload.clicked.connect(page.reload)

        home = widget.QPushButton(gui.QIcon('home.png'), '')
        # home.clicked.connect(self.home)

        bookmark = widget.QPushButton(self)
        # bookmark.clicked.connect(self.bookmark)

        return back, forward, reload, home, bookmark

    def setupLayout(self):
        self.layout = widget.QWidget()
        grid = widget.QVBoxLayout(self.layout)

        self.navigationLayout = widget.QWidget()
        navigation = widget.QHBoxLayout(self.navigationLayout)

        navigation.addWidget(self.buttons[0], 0)
        navigation.addWidget(self.buttons[1], 0)
        navigation.addWidget(self.buttons[2], 0)
        navigation.addWidget(self.buttons[3], 0)
        navigation.addWidget(self.url, 1)
        navigation.addWidget(self.buttons[4], 0)

        grid.addWidget(self.navigationLayout, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.page, 1)

    def xxx(self):
        print(self)
        self.url.setText('work')
```

**browser**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as widget

from page_2 import Page

class Browser(widget.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupPages()

    def setupPages(self):
        self.pages = widget.QTabWidget(self)
        self.pages.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.pages.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.closeTab)

        self.setupAddTabButton(self.pages)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.pages)

    def setupAddTabButton(self, pages):
        pages.addTab(widget.QWidget(), '')

        add_tab_button = widget.QToolButton()
        add_tab_button.setText('+')
        add_tab_button.setAutoRaise(True)
        add_tab_button.clicked.connect(self.tab)
        pages.tabBar().setTabButton(0, widget.QTabBar.RightSide, add_tab_button)

    def tab(self):
        index = self.pages.count() - 1
        self.pages.insertTab(index, Page().layout, f'Page {index}')
        self.pages.setCurrentIndex(index)

    def closeTab(self, index):
        self.pages.removeTab(index)
```

**main**

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

from browser import Browser


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

browser = Browser()
browser.showMaximized()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите, у вас в `page_2.py` немного намудрено с GUI в методе `setupLayout`.

Попробуйте так:

```
def setupLayout(self):
    grid = widget.QVBoxLayout()

    self.navigationLayout = widget.QWidget()
    navigation = widget.QHBoxLayout(self.navigationLayout)

    navigation.addWidget(self.buttons[0], 0)
    navigation.addWidget(self.buttons[1], 0)
    navigation.addWidget(self.buttons[2], 0)
    navigation.addWidget(self.buttons[3], 0)
    navigation.addWidget(self.url, 1)
    navigation.addWidget(self.buttons[4], 0)

    grid.addWidget(self.navigationLayout, 0)
    grid.addWidget(self.page, 1)

    self.setLayout(grid)
```

Тогда, в `browser.py` пишите так:

```
self.pages.insertTab(index, Page(), f'Page {index}')
```

---

Почему в вашей реализации не работает `url.returnPressed.connect(self.xxx)` не знаю, можно только строить теории.

Кст, а вот `url.returnPressed.connect(lambda: self.xxx())` должно работать, но почему тоже не знаю

Comment: Как раз после этого изменения моя реализация стала работать